# wget "missing URL"

Tags: shell

I am simply looking up the latest version of "go" and storing it in the URL path.

```
url="$(wget -qO- https://golang.org/dl/ | grep -oP 'https:\/\/dl\.google\.com\/go\/go([0-9\.]+)\.linux-amd64\.tar\.gz' | head -n 1 )"
```

When I echo, the output is blank.
Also, when I try and download the file like this:

```
wget ${url}
```

I receive the following error message:

```
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

Comment: `wget` is not at all the problem here! That's like saying the bend in the road is the problem after not tightening the bolts holding your wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see, you are trying to match on a full URL, and the page only contains relative hrefs. Here is an example of one:

```
<tr>
  <td class="filename"><a class="download" href="/dl/go1.3rc1.linux-386.tar.gz">go1.3rc1.linux-386.tar.gz</a></td>
  <td>Archive</td>
  <td>Linux</td>
  <td>x86</td>
  <td></td>
  <td><tt>07c656173c444e4373a799141c1cb28128a345eb</tt></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see from above, the download href does not contain the full path. So if you want to match the relative path, you can do:

```
url="$(wget -qO- https://golang.org/dl/ | grep 'class="download"'| awk -F "\"" '{print $6}' | head -n1 | sed  's/^/https\:\/\/golang\.org/')"
```

Where:

```
grep 'class="download"'
```

Will find all lines that are download links (If you trust the page has a rather stable format, you can skip this step)

```
awk -F "\"" '{print $6}'
```

Reads the lines as double-quote separated fields, and prints the 6th field, which happens to be the relative href; and

```
sed  's/^/https\:\/\/golang\.org/')"
```

this prefixes the site, so you end up with a full URL. Of course this would fail if the Site changes, so you might want to make use a variable to store the site, and then use that variable on both the wget query and the sed query.... But Web **scraping** has these kind of quirks.